# is "intriguity" an actual word?

Tags: word-usage, nouns, american-english, is-it-a-word

Intriguity as in "the state of being intrigued; curiosity"?

I saw it being used by writers multiple times, but now that I wanted to use it myself, I tried searching it up in the dictionaries and found only one that has an entry for this word.

Comment: No it isn't a word in 2019, but I think it will be in a few years time.

Comment: Could you provide an example where the writer has used this word?

Comment: Uities tend to be derived from the uous, but I've never heard of the intriguous.

Answer (score 1):

It is not formally recognized (yet) by any dictionary of which I am aware, which is the usual metric for "real" English words. The closest words I can think of that conveys the same meaning might be *fascination* or *interest*.

Comment: "Fascination" would work as a synonym...

Answer (score 0):

No. The noun form is "intrigue". 
I find it hard to believe that several writers use "intriguity"... unless you include the copywriters for the advertising material of the Indian IT company of that name: http://www.intriguity.com/

Answer (score -1):

It is a "real word" in the sense that it is something that is attributed a colloquial, informal definition.

It is not a "real word" in the sense that it is in the dictionary.

If the word catches on, it could possibly earn an entry.